# On Riesz criteria for Riemann hypothesis:

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis, analytic-functions

Marcel Riesz defined a function :

$R(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n x^n} {\zeta(2n)\Gamma(n)}$

The Riemann hypothesis holds if $R(x)= O( x^{1/4 + {\varepsilon}}$)
For any  $\varepsilon$

We have a relatively trivial bound  $O(x^{1/2})$

Also various standard properties can be extracted from basic zeta function theory .

> > Questions:

> > (1) Does exponent between (1/4) and (1/2) for bound exists. i.e is there a bound better than $x^{1/2}$ but weaker than $x^{1/4 + {\varepsilon}}$?

> > (2) If such intermediate bound is achieved , what equivalent property about zeroes of Zeta function would be proved ?

> > (3) $R(x)$  looks lot like Taylor or any other symmetrical functional expansion . Is there any possible compact form for $R(x)$?

Comment: Online on MO after long time , anything new on the question ?

Comment: The formula 2.4 ($\frac{\Gamma(1-s/2)}{\zeta(s)}=\int_0^{\infty}x^{-s/2-1}R(x)dx$) in Broughan Equivalents of the Riemann Hypothesis II clearly shows that any estimate $R(x)= O( x^{c + {\varepsilon}}), 1/4 \le c <1/2$ gives a non zero halfplane $\Re s >2c$ for the RZ

Comment: @Conrad The integral associated with the Mellin transform of $x^n$ doesn't converge (the result is actually a distribution). Was a different formula than the OP's for $R(x)$ used to evaluate the Mellin transform integral?

Comment: @Steven not sure I understand the question; it is known (and easy to prove by Mobius inversion) that $R(x)=O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for large $x$ and $R(x) << x$ for small $0<x<1$ which means that $x^{-s/2-1}R(x)$ is integrable at both ends for $\Re s \in [1+\delta, 2-\delta], \epsilon < \delta <1/2$ and it is a matter of computation to show that the Mellin transform is $\Gamma (1-s/2)/\zeta(s)$ while if we have a better estimate for large $x$ we extend the left integrability to $2c+\delta, 1/4 \le c < 1/2$ so extend the zero free region of $\zeta$ to $\Re s >2c$ as $\delta$ is arbitrary

Comment: @Conrad I don't believe the Mellin transform can be derived term-wise from the OP's formula, but I see now the Mellin transform can be derived term-wise from the alternate formula $R(x)=x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} e^{-\frac{x}{n^2}}$.

Comment: @Steven yes I agree - both estimates and formulas are best deduced from the Mobius inversion formula; the original series is "catchier" but less useful

Comment: @Conrad IMO the idea of Riesz's criterion is that for $R(x)=x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} e^{-\frac{x}{n^2}}$ the standard Tauberian theorems give a RH criterion in term of the growth of $R(x)$ near $0$, and expanding the power series $R(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n x^n}  {\zeta(2n)\Gamma(n)}$ using the expression for $\zeta(2n)$ in term of Bernouilli numbers we get that $R(x)$ is also defined as the *additive* convolution inverse of $\Re(\frac{e^{2i\pi x}}{2i\pi x -1})$ on $|x|=1$, which is a bit unexpected (in *multiplicative* number theory).

Comment: (I meant $R(x^2)$). Moreover $R(x)$ has an explicit formula in term of the zeros, but the functional equation gets more complicated than for $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n \log  \zeta(2n)\Gamma(n)$. As usual trying to find how those functions behave differently when replacing $\zeta(s)$ by $\overline{w}^{-1/2}L(s,\chi_5)+\overline{w}^{-1/2}L(s,\overline{\chi_5})$ is a headache.

Comment: @reuns the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} e^{-\frac{x}{n^2}}$ is absolutely convergent so for small $x$ we cannot do better than $R(x)=O(x)$ but for large $x$ we get at least a $\sqrt x$ saving (standard proof splits the sum to $n>\sqrt x$ and trivial estimation and then $n < \sqrt x$ where an integral test works; if we can do better for large $x$ (which obviously heurisitically means lots of cancellation for $\mu$) we can extend the holomorphy domain of $1/\zeta$

Comment: @Conrad Yes a lot of typo but you are supposed to see the idea, I meant growth at $\infty$ and "almost" the convolution inverse (the inverse convoluted by $\exp$). The point is what I wrote: unexpected apparence of additive convolution in the RH, hard to find how the Euler product comes into play, difficulty to use the explicit formula and the functional equation. A last point:  this class of functions is interesting because they encode not only the RH but also the GRH.

Comment: (as a Mellin convolution sends $\sum_n \mu(n) n^{-2}e^{-x/n^2}$ to  $\sum_n \mu(n) n^{-2} e^{-xn^2}$)